# Popup on footer to make an email list

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I'm creating a simple popup to be shown on footer of pages to make a email list.

I would like you to give a look at the code below if possible .. and would appreciate some suggestions in respect of the logic applied and the form of how the code was encoded.

Live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vsilva472/6aqvu83y/)

```
var App = App || {};

App._elements = App._elements || {};

// Container
App._elements.container = App._elements.container || {};
App._elements.container._element = jQuery( '<div />' );
App._elements.container.callback = function(){
    this._element.attr( 'id', 'main' );
};

// Header
App._elements.header = App._elements.header || {};
App._elements.header._element = jQuery( '<div />' );
App._elements.header.callback = function(){
    this._element
    .appendTo( App._elements.container._element )
    .click( function() {

        if( App._elements.container._element.hasClass( 'active' ) ){
            App.animate.hide();
            return;
        }

        App.animate.show();
    }); 
};

// Header Container
App._elements.headerContainer = App._elements.headerContainer || {};
App._elements.headerContainer._element = jQuery( '<div />' );
App._elements.headerContainer.callback = function(){
    this._element
        .appendTo( App._elements.header._element )
        .addClass( 'headerContainer' );
};

// Close Button
App._elements.closeButton = App._elements.closeButton || {};
App._elements.closeButton._element = jQuery( '<a />' );
App._elements.closeButton.callback = function(){

    this._element
        .appendTo( App._elements.headerContainer._element )
        .click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            App._elements.container._element.remove();
        })
        .addClass( 'closeButton' );
};

// Content
App._elements.content = App._elements.content || {};
App._elements.content._element = jQuery( '<div />' );
App._elements.content.callback = function(){
    this._element
        .appendTo( App._elements.container._element );
};

// Description
App._elements.description = App._elements.description || {};
App._elements.description._element = jQuery( '<p />' );
App._elements.description.callback = function(){
    this._element.appendTo( App._elements.content._element );
};

// Description
App._elements.email_field = App._elements.email_field || {};
App._elements.email_field._element = jQuery( '<input />' );
App._elements.email_field.callback = function(){
    this._element
        .attr({
            'type' : 'text',
            'name' : 'email',
            'id': 'emailField',
        })
        .appendTo( App._elements.content._element );
};

// Close Button
App._elements.submitButton = App._elements.submitButton || {};
App._elements.submitButton._element = jQuery( '<a />' );
App._elements.submitButton.callback = function(){
    this._element
        .appendTo( App._elements.content._element )
        .click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert( 'Send!' );
        })
        .attr( 'id', 'buttonClass' );
};

// Loader
App._elements.loader = App._elements.loader || {};
App._elements.loader._element = jQuery( '<img />' );
App._elements.loader.callback = function(){
    this._element
        .appendTo( App._elements.content._element )
        .attr( 'src' , 'data:image/gif;base64,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' )
        .hide();
};

// Loader
App._elements.privacy = App._elements.privacy || {};
App._elements.privacy._element = jQuery( '<small />' );
App._elements.privacy.callback = function(){
    this._element
        .appendTo( App._elements.content._element );
};

App.animate = App.animate || {};
App.animate.init = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 200, function(){ 
            App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-270px' }, 50, function(){
                App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 50, function(){
                    App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-270px' }, 50, function(){
                        App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 50 );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }, 1500);
};

App.animate.show = function(){              
    App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '0' }, 50, function(){ 
        App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-50px' }, 50, function(){
            App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '0' }, 50, function(){
                App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-20px' }, 50, function(){
                    App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '0' }, 50 );
                });
            });
        });
    }).addClass( 'active' );
};

App.animate.hide = function(){          
    App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-305px' }, 200, function(){
        App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-245px' }, 200, function(){ 
            App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-250px' }, 50, function(){
                App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 50, function(){
                    App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-275px' }, 50, function(){
                        App._elements.container._element.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 50 );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }).removeClass( 'active' );
};

App.build = function() {
    for( var i in App._elements ) {
        if( App._elements[i].hasOwnProperty( 'msg' ) ) {
            App._elements[i]._element.html( App._elements[i].msg );
        }

        if( App._elements[i].hasOwnProperty( 'placeholder' ) ) {
            App._elements[i]._element.html( App._elements[i].placeholder );
        }

        if( App._elements[i].hasOwnProperty( '_css' ) ) {
            App._elements[i]._element.css( App._elements[i]._css );
        }

        if( App._elements[i].hasOwnProperty( 'callback' ) ) {
            App._elements[i].callback();
        }
    }

    App._elements.content._element.appendTo( App._elements.container._element );
    App._elements.container._element.appendTo( 'body' );

    App.animate.init();
};

/* CLIENT CUSTOMIZATIONS BELLOW... CHANGE TO WHAT YOU WANT */
App._elements.container._css = { 
    'position'  : 'fixed',
    'width'     : '355px',
    'height'    : '305px',
    'bottom'    : '-310px',
    'right'     : '25px',
    'background': '#f5f5f5',
    'boxSizing' : 'border-box',
    'fontFamily': 'verdana',
    'border'    : '1px solid #E1E1E1',
    'zIndex'    : 999
};

App._elements.header._css = {
    'height'    : '40px',
    'maxHeight' : '40px',
    'background': "#e1e1e1",
    'cursor'    : 'pointer',
    'boxSizing' : 'border-box',
    'padding'   : '10px',
    'color'     : '#fff'
};

App._elements.headerContainer._css = {
    'position' : 'relavite',
    'fontSize' : '17px',
    'fontFamily' : '"Open Sans", verdana',
    'font-weight' : 'bold',
    'letterSpacing' : '0.5px',
    'textTransform' : 'uppercase'
};

App._elements.headerContainer.msg = "Click to expand/contract";

App._elements.closeButton._css = {
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'right' : '10px',
    'top' : '0px',
    'display' : 'inline-block',
    'padding' : '10px',
    'color' : '#fff',
    'fontFamily' : 'verdana',
    'textDecoration' : 'none',
    'fontWeight': 'bold'
};

App._elements.closeButton.msg = 'x';

App._elements.description.msg = 'Enter your email bellow <br />and receive our newsletter.';

App._elements.description._css = {
    'fontSize' : '13.5px',
    'textAlign' : 'center',
    'color' : '#333333',
    'fontFamily' : 'Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif',
    'margin' : '10px 0 25px',
    'lineHeight' : '17px',
    'letterSpacing' : '0.7px'
};

App._elements.email_field._css = {
    'border' : '1px solid #666',
    'padding' : '5px 10px',
    'fontSize' : '14px',
    'margin' : '0 0 20px 0',
    'width' : '310px',
    'border': '1px solid #d7d7d7'
};

App._elements.email_field.placeholder = "Your email...";

App._elements.submitButton._css = {
    'display' : 'block',
    'border' : '0',
    'color' : '#fff',
    'textTransform' : 'uppercase',
    'padding' : '0px',
    'width' : '184px',
    'height' : '39px',
    'margin' : '0 auto',
    'textAlign' : 'center',
    'fontFamily' : 'verdana',
    'cursor' :  'pointer',
    'background' : '#666666',
    'line-height' : '35px'
};

App._elements.submitButton.msg = "Go!";

App._elements.loader._css = {
    'display' : 'block',
    'margin'  : '0 auto'
};

App._elements.privacy._css = {
    'display' : 'block',
    'color' : '#333',
    'fontSize' : '10px',
    'textAlign' : 'center',
    'fontFamily' : 'Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif',
    'marginTop' : '20px',
    'letterSpacing' : '0px'
};

App._elements.privacy.msg = "We respect your privacy<br />and not will send spam.";

App._elements.content._css = {
    'boxSizing' : 'border-box',
    'padding' : '10px',
    'fontFamily' : 'Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif',
    'color' : '#333',
    'lineHeight' : '14px'
};

App.build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, it seems like you use global variables. It is not good
   practice in javascript. You can read about it
   [here](http://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2013/05/properly-isolate-variables-in-javascript/)
   for example or just google 'javascript global variables best
   practice'. I just can say that you can wrap your code with this:

   ```
   (function($) {
   // your code
   })(jQuery);
   ```

   [What it is](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/).
2. What is the purpose of this code `var App = App || {};`? Such a
   method is used when you have some modules, that are in different
   files. So every module uses `App` variable and you don't know the
   order a module loads. But in you example there is one file (one
   script) and furthermore it is not likely some other modules will be
   used `App` variable. So you can just write `var App = {}`. This problem you have also with defining of properties - `App._elements.container = App._elements.container || {};`.
3. There is no need to repeat `App._elements.container` when you define
   properties:

   ```
   var App = {
       _elements: {
           container: {
               _element: $('<div />'),
               callback: function(){
                   this._element.attr( 'id', 'main' );
               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Or you can first define elements and then match them to `App`
   properties:

   ```js
   var container: {
           _element: $('<div />'),
           callback: function(){
               this._element.attr( 'id', 'main' );
           };
       };

   var App = {
       _elements: {
           container: container
       }
   };
   ```
4. I advice you to use [template
   engines](http://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-templating-engines/).
   Of course, if you just have this code or this is a library, you
   don't have to load large template library. But in other ways this
   can improve your code orginizing.
5. Follow [DRY
   principle](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-key-software-principles-you-must-understand--net-25161)
   (first principle in the link) or
   [google](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+dry+principle).
   In `animate.hide` and `animate.show` you repeat
   `App._elements.container._element` a lot of times. You can create
   varibale `el` and use it instead of
   `App._elements.container._element`:

   ```
   var el = App._elements.container._element;
   el.animate( { 'bottom' : '-305px' }, 200, function(){
       el.animate( { 'bottom' : '-245px' }, 200, function(){ 
           el.animate( { 'bottom' : '-250px' }, 50, function(){
               el.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 50, function(){
                   el.animate( { 'bottom' : '-275px' }, 50, function(){
                       el.animate( { 'bottom' : '-265px' }, 50 );
                   });
               });
           });
       });
   }).removeClass( 'active' );
   ```

   Also I added private method `_animate` to `App.animate`:

   ```
   _animate: function(props) {
       props.map(function(config) {
           return function(cb) {
               App._elements.container._element.animate({bottom: config.bottom}, config.duration, cb);
           };
       }).forEach(function(fn, i, ar) {
         fn(ar[i + 1]);
       });
   }
   ```

   And now your 'animate.show` method, for example, will be:

   ```
   this._animate([
     {
       bottom: 0,
       duration: 50
     }, {
       bottom: -50,
       duration: 50
     }, {
       bottom: 0,
       duration: 50
     }, {
       bottom: -20,
       duration: 50
     }, {
       bottom: 0,
       duration: 50
     }
   ]);
   ```

   As you can see, code becomes a little cleaner. So, what the
   `animate._animate` method does. It takes and array of params for
   jQuery `animate` functions: bottom - is css bottom, duration - is
   animation duration. Then it make callbacks functions with `map`
   function ([mdn
   link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).
   In your code callback is function whick executes when previos
   animation ends. And then using `forEach` it run animate, passing
   needed callback. This may be difficult to understand, but you can
   observe this function in your own.

Comment: Please! Tell me where you see a global variable?

Comment: `App` is a global variable.

Comment: You're right,,, one more question... the map function used in _animate.. is ecmascript map or jQuery.map?

Comment: map and forEach are ecmascript. But if you want cross-browser solution jQuery has such methods as well. However jQuery has them as static methods, but native ones exist for all arrays.